# VB: Crash when multiplied by a negative number

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to create a program that you can enter a mathematical expression into and it outputs the result. I've run into an issue where the program crashes whenever I multiply a number by a negative number. This only occurs when the negative number is on the right to a negative number. The program also crashes when the power is negative.

```vb
    Private Function OpCode(Expression)
        PopulateLists(Expression) 
        Dim OpIndex As Integer
        Dim NewNum As Double
        Dim operators = {"^", "*", "+"} 
        'Note: no minus sign, the minus goes with the number.
        For Each op In operators
            Do
                OpIndex = OperatorList.IndexOf(op) 
                If OpIndex = -1 Then 
                    Exit Do 
                End If
                Select Case op 
                    Case "^"
                        NewNum = NumList(OpIndex) ^ NumList(OpIndex + 1)
                    Case "*" 
                        NewNum = NumList(OpIndex) * NumList(OpIndex + 1)
                    Case "+" 
                        NewNum = NumList(OpIndex) + NumList(OpIndex + 1)
                End Select
                NumList.RemoveAt(OpIndex + 1) 
                NumList(OpIndex) = NewNum
                OperatorList.RemoveAt(OpIndex) 
            Loop
        Next
        Return NumList(0) 
    End Function

    Private Sub PopulateLists(Expression As String) 
        Dim strNum As String = ""
        For Each c As Char In Expression
            If Char.IsDigit(c) Then
                strNum &= c
            ElseIf c = "-" Then 
                OperatorList.Add("+") 
                NumList.Add(CDbl(strNum))
                strNum = "-"
                'Add the last number we accumulated so we can start a new one with the minus sign
            Else
                OperatorList.Add(c)
                NumList.Add(CDbl(strNum))
                
                strNum = ""
            End If
        Next
        NumList.Add(CInt(strNum))
    End Sub
```

Here's what I tried:

```
Private Sub PopulateLists(Expression As String)
        Dim strNum As String = ""
        For c = 0 To Expression.Length - 1
            If Char.IsDigit(Expression(c))
                strNum &= Expression(c)
            ElseIf Expression(c) = "-" And Char.IsDigit(Expression(c - 1)) Then
                OperatorList.Add("+")
                NumList.Add(CDbl(strNum))
                strNum = "-"
            Else
                OperatorList.Add(Expression(c))
                NumList.Add(CDbl(strNum)) 'Add the last number we accumulated so we can start a new one with the minus sign
                If c = Expression.Length - 1 Then
                    strNum = ""
                ElseIf Expression(c + 1) = "-"
                    strNum = "-"
                Else
                    strNum = ""
                End If

            End If
        Next
        NumList.Add(CInt(strNum))
    End Sub
```

This didn't work. If I input for example, 4*-3, I get the error 'conversion from "-" to type 'Double' is not valid'.
If anyone knows a fix for this, please let me know.
Thank you!

Comment: why the `C#` and `vba` tags?  this is niether.

Comment: @ScottCraner Sorry, how do I get rid of them?

Comment: If you want to avoid other potential crashes, you may prefer to use `Double.TryParse` instead of `CDbl` to do your string-to-double conversions.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I tried playing around with the code and found a solution:

```
Else
    If Expression(c) = "-" Then
        Continue For
    End If
    OperatorList.Add(Expression(c))
    NumList.Add(CDbl(strNum))
    If c = Expression.Length - 1 Then
        strNum = "" 
    ElseIf Expression(c + 1) = "-" Then
        strNum = "-"

    Else
        strNum = ""
    End If

End If
```

Answer (score 0):

When an operator precedes a negative number we must check for null or empty before adding to the `OperatorList` or the `NumList`. There will probably be more kinks to work out.

```
Private Sub PopulateLists(Input As String)
    Dim strNum As String = ""
    For Each c As Char In Input 'Be careful here, the IDE wants to add () at the end of this line - it doesn't belong
        If Char.IsDigit(c) Then
            strNum &= c
        ElseIf c = "-" Then
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(strNum) Then
                OperatorList.Add("+") 'We are adding a negative number
                NumList.Add(CDbl(strNum)) 'Add the last number we accumulated so we can start a new one with the minus sign
            End If
            strNum = "-" 'Start a new number with the minus sign
        Else 'The other operators are added to the list
            OperatorList.Add(c)
            NumList.Add(CDbl(strNum))
            strNum = ""
        End If
    Next
    NumList.Add(CInt(strNum)) 'The last number which will not be followed by an operator
End Sub
```